# PDO exception is : "No Database Connection"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't find any way to connect to database with pdo; I tried the folowing syntax .

I have php7 and and pdo support mysql database

`ConnectDb` class:

```
class ConnectDb {
    private $username = "admin";
    private $password = "passw";
    private $connection = NULL;

    protected function __construct($dbname)
    {
        try
        {
            $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . "127.0.0.1" . ";dbname=" . $dbname . ";charset=utf8;",$this->username,$this->password,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOException $exception){
            echo $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }

    protected function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

Insert data class

```
class InsertDb extends ConnectDb
{
    function __construct($dbname)
    {
        parent::__construct($dbname);
        $this->insert();
    }

    private function insert()
    {
        if ($this->getConnection() !== NULL) {
            $savequer = "INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $savedPdo = $this->getConnection()->prepare($savequer);
            $savedPdo->execute(array($_POST['firstName'], $_POST['lastName'],$_POST['email'], $_POST['password']));
        } else {
            echo "No Database Connection";
        }
    }
}
```

and my object

```
new InsertDb("tamrin01");
```

No Database Connection

Comment: I don't understand the reason for those classes. However - you need to use `$this->connection = ...` instead of `$connection = ...`. I'm voting to close this as typo question.

Comment: Don't open a new connection every time you need to run a statement. If you aren't lucky with garbage collection you're going to kill your server for no good reason.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel Thank you so much so I'm forgetting "$this->" :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I followed your description and got familiar with Singleton algorithm. Is Singleton on the web? I apologize for Google Translate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In get_connection function you return class members connection. but in constructor you are using new variable to create a database connection.

It will be like.

```
protected function __construct($dbname)
    {
        try
        {
          //Create a database connection with class member connection. Don't use new variable $connection.
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8;",$this->username,$this->password,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOException $exception){
            echo $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: tnx bro :) i forget "$this"